# PowerShell: different result with and without string interpolation (with Get-Date -DisplayHint Time)

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

When I run `Get-Date -DisplayHint Time`, the output is `10:30:19`.

When I run `"$(Get-Date -DisplayHint Time)"`, the output is `02/15/2018 10:30:15`.

Why the difference?

```
PSVersion = 5.1.16299.98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `-DisplayHint` is, well, a display hint. The result of the cmdlet is still a `DateTime` object. Inside a string the expression doesn't count as being "displayed", and you will get... something else. (Curiously, it's not the result of a simple `.ToString()`). Use `"$(Get-Date -Format 'T')"` if you want the locale-dependent long time format inside a string (which is apparently what `-DisplayHint Time` will do, although that's not explicitly documented as such).